# Как повесить событие клика на элементы с одинаковыми классами jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

подскажите пожалуйста есть 7 списков (li), на один я повесил клик для появление блока с текстом снизу. Как сделать для оставшихся 6, чтобы не менять и не делать разные классы ? Можно ли для одинаковых классов сделать событие click. (Блок в виде списка ul и li)

```js
 $('.faq-item').click(function () {
    $('.faq-item__hide').toggle();
    $('.fas.fa-chevron-up.fa-up').toggleClass('animate-rotate');
  });
```

```html
<ul class="faq-list">
<li class="faq-item">I have doubts.<i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-up"></i>
<p class="faqitem__hide">llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll.</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ну можно. в текущнм коде это должно работать. В чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема нажимаешь на любой из семи блоков открывается первый, а не каждый по отдельности.

Comment: Это совсем другая проблема, не та, что описана в вопросе

Comment: $('.faq-item__one').click(function () {
    $('.faq-hide__one').toggle();
    $('.fa-up__one').toggleClass('animate-rotate');
  });

  $('.faq-item__two').click(function () {
    $('.faq-hide__two').toggle();
    $('.fa-up__two').toggleClass('animate-rotate');
  });

При дублировании, меняешь класс все работает. Но как этого избежать, чтобы это не копировать ?

Comment: Проблема просто заключается в том, что нужно следить не за общими классами, а классами контекста, то есть применять например `$(this)` в связке с `.next` или `children` и  т.д.

Comment: Я понимаю про $(this), но не понимаю как это вставить правильно ?

Comment: Спасибо большое и огромное !!

Comment: У меня ещё маленький вопрос а на hover сработает такое решение ?  $('.front-one').mouseover(function(){
  $('.front-one').hide();
  $('.back-one').show();
});

$('.back-one').mouseout(function(){
  $('.front-one').show();
  $('.back-one').hide();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.faq-item', function() {
  $(this).children('.faqitem__hide').toggle();
  $(this).children('.fa-up').toggleClass('animate-rotate');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="faq-list">
  <li class="faq-item">I have doubts.<i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-up"></i>
    <p class="faqitem__hide">llllllllllllllllllllll.</p>
  </li>
  
  <li class="faq-item">222.<i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-up"></i>
    <p class="faqitem__hide">222 text .</p>
  </li>
  
  <li class="faq-item">333.<i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-up"></i>
    <p class="faqitem__hide">333 text.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Алексей большое спасибо ! Дай бог вам здоровья !